# db2 as a service in Cloud foundry

Tags: db2, cloud-foundry, db2-luw

Im trying to connect to db2 service defined in my Cloudfoundry and it is bound to my application.

```
@Configuration
@ServiceScan
@Profile("cloud")
public class Db2CloudConfig extends AbstractCloudConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource db2servicenew() {

        CloudFactory cloudFactory = new CloudFactory();
        Cloud cloud = cloudFactory.getCloud();
        DB2ServiceInfo db2ServiceInfo= (DB2ServiceInfo) cloud.getServiceInfo("db2servicenew"); 
        return cloud.getServiceConnector(db2ServiceInfo.getId(), DataSource.class, null);

    }

    @Bean(name = "db2JdbcTemplate") 
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource db2servicenew) { 
        return new JdbcTemplate(db2servicenew); 
    } 

}
```

I have added below 2 files in resource Path /META-INF/services

```
org.springframework.cloud.cloudfoundry.CloudFoundryServiceInfoCreator(File)
org.springframework.cloud.cloudfoundry.DB2ServiceInfoCreator

org.springframework.cloud.service.ServiceConnectorCreator (File)
org.springframework.cloud.service.relational.DB2DataSourceCreator
```

Getting below error

> 2016-07-14T03:19:44.44-0400 [APP/0] OUT 2016-07-14 07:19:44.444 WARN
>   14 --- [ main] o.c.r.o.s.cloud.AbstractCloudConnector : No suitable
>   service info creator found for service db2-srvc Did you forget to add
>   a ServiceInfoCreator?

2016-07-14T03:19:44.51-0400 [APP/0] OUT 2016-07-14 07:19:44.510 INFO 14 --- [ main] nfigurationApplicationContextInitializer : Adding cloud service auto-reconfiguration to ApplicationContext
2016-07-14T03:19:45.15-0400 [APP/0] OUT 2016-07-14 07:19:45.154 INFO 14 --- [ main] c.e.config.ApplicationIntializer : Cloud profile active

.....

.....

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'db2service' defined in class path resource [com/eclipselite/config/Db2CloudConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'db2service' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.cloud.service.BaseServiceInfo cannot be cast to org.springframework.cloud.service.common.DB2ServiceInfo
2016-07-14T03:19:52.50-0400 [APP/0] OUT at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
2016-07-14T03:19:52.50-0400 [APP/0] OUT at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
2016-07-14T03:19:52.50-0400 [APP/0] OUT at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
2016-07-14T03:19:52.50-0400 [APP/0] OUT at org.springframework.beans.factory.support

......

......

:52.50-0400 [APP/0] OUT Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.cloud.service.BaseServiceInfo cannot be cast to org.springframework.cloud.service.common.DB2ServiceInfo
2016-07-14T03:19:52.50-0400 [APP/0] OUT at com.eclipselite.config.Db2CloudConfig.db2service(Db2CloudConfig.java:43) ~[app/:na]
2016-07-14T03:19:52.50-0400 [APP/0] OUT at com.eclipselite.config.Db2CloudConfig$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$95090e1d.CGLIB$db2service$1() ~[app/:na]
2016-07-14T03:19:52.50-0400 [APP/0] OUT at com.eclipselite.config.Db2CloudConfig$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$95090e1d$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$5de8a91d.invoke() ~[app/:na]
2016-07-14T03:19:52.50-0400 [APP/0] OUT at org.springfr

Comment: Are you referring to the "DB2 on Cloud" service on Bluemix or other scenarios? Where is your CF environment hosted? Please add details about the general setup

Comment: We have a private Cloud in our organisation, associated with Pivotal Cloud foundry. We have db2 database within the same GRN. Im able to access the same db2 directly. but when i define the same as user-defined service getting the above error.

Answer (score 0):

I think If you are creating using serviceInfo  it looks for certain tags/properties in cups. You can create a data source using connectionFactory.datasource("cups service name") or define the cups correctly as mentioned in the following document http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-connectors/spring-cloud-cloud-foundry-connector.html#_db2

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Your answer could be better. [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) can help you write answers that will be accepted and upvoted.